# User Authentication in BizTalk Published Orchestration as WCF-WSHttp

Tags: biztalk, wcf-security, biztalk-2010

I have published an orchestration as a WCF web service using WCF_WSHttp bindings.  I think we about the SSL certificate working.  It will be open to the internet, thus anyone who knows the URL could call it and pass data; so we want to add user/pass authentication.  We simply one the one client/vendor to have the ability to call this webservice, no one else.

I've been reading everywhere, and cannot find any specific steps.
I think I want something like Scenario #4 here: https://seroter.wordpress.com/biztalk-and-wcf-part-ii-security-patterns/, but I cannot see how he got the "Client Credentials" box to pop-up in BT-2010.

Best I can tell is I have to:

1) In BizTalk Admin Console - set Security Mode to TransportWithMessageCredential.

2) From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226482.aspx, I'm a little confused about the difference between Windows and Username.  An outside vendor is calling our webservice, so they are not on our domain.  Do I need to set up a service account?  Or can I just make up a username and insert it here somewhere?

3) Do I have to make corresponding changes to the WCF web.config that was created by the BT-2010 "WCF Servcie Publishing Wizard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your're looking for just Basic authentication on the transport layer? All you then have to do is to create an AD user or a local user on the BizTalk machine and set the `Transport client credential type` to `Basic`.

Comment: Just to be specific: 1) app.config of client program needs this:   <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" /> 2) BizTalk rcv location - Security Tab - set Transport client credential type to Basic.